# Cómo puedo iterar una lista para que muestre todos sus elementos e introducirlos en un Combobox de tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Quiero introducir en un Combobox una lista de valores que se vayan actualizando según lo que devuelva una consulta de sqlite3; esta consulta se va almacenando es una lista, esto fue lo que intente:

```
rows=MyCursor.fetchall()

row=([i for (i,) in rows])

CuadroID["values"]=[row]
```

Pero a la hora de introducir los valores, estos se colocan en fila y no en una columna/lista desplegable, y no sé como colocarlos cada uno de los datos es una fila del Combobox, que cada uno represente un valor, y no todos un único valor.

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos una tabla como:

> ```
> ╔══════════╦══════╗
> ║ Lenguaje ║ Año  ║
> ╠══════════╬══════╣
> ║ "Python" ║ 1991 ║
> ║ "Rust"   ║ 2010 ║
> ║ "C++"    ║ 1983 ║
> ║ "C"      ║ 1972 ║
> ╚══════════╩══════╝
> ```

Primero, `fetchall` retorna una lista de tuplas de la forma:

```
[('Python', '1991'), ('Rust', '2010'), ('C++', '1983'), ('C', '1972')] # SELECT *
```

o:

```
[('Python',), ('Rust',), ('C++',), ('C',)] # SELECT Lenguaje
```

Con `row=([i for (i,) in rows])`, asumiendo que tu tabla tiene una sola columna o que limitas el `SELECT` a una sola obtienes algo como:

```
['Python', 'Rust', 'C++', 'C']
```

Que es una lista con los valores de la primera columna de la consulta y **que puedes pasar ya directamente al `Combobox`**:

```
CuadroID["values"] = row
```

De hecho, es más eficiente que no uses fetchall y generes la lista por compresión directamente iterando sobre el cursor:

```
rows = [i for (i, *_) in MyCursor]
CuadroID["values"] = row
```

Si haces `CuadroID["values"]=[row]` le pasas:

```
[['Python', 'Rust', 'C++', 'C']]
```

por lo que solo agrega un item a la lista dado que la lista solo tiene un item, otra lista.

Un ejemplo completo reproducible usando sqlite:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


db = sqlite3.connect("")  # BD temporal en memoria 
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test(Lenguaje TEXT, Año TEXT)")
cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO test VAlUES(?, ?)",
    (("Python", 1991), ("Rust", 2010), ("C++", 1983), ("C", 1972))
    )

def consulta():
    cursor.execute("SELECT Lenguaje FROM test")
    combo["values"] = [i for (i, *_) in cursor]

root = tk.Tk()
combo = ttk.Combobox(root)
combo.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
tk.Button(
    root, text="Consulta", command=consulta
    ).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

root.mainloop()
cursor.close()
db.close()
```